# Code is running but total price calculation is wrong

Tags: java

I'm having an error with the total price because the calculation is always wrong. I rechecked my code and the formulas were just right.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hans
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        final int EGG_DOZEN = 12;
        final double DOZEN_PRICE = 3.25;
        final double EGG_PRICE = 0.45;
        int eggs; 
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("How many eggs has been ordered: ");
        eggs = keyboard.nextInt();

        int answer = eggs/EGG_DOZEN;
        int remainder = eggs%EGG_DOZEN;
        double SingleEgg = EGG_PRICE * remainder;
        double DozenEgg =DOZEN_PRICE * EGG_DOZEN;
        double TotalPrice = SingleEgg + DozenEgg;

        System.out.print ("You odered "+ eggs + " eggs.That's " + answer + " dozen at " + DOZEN_PRICE + "$ per dozen and " + remainder + " loosen eggs at " + EGG_PRICE+" cents each for a total of " + TotalPrice + "$");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do `double DozenEgg =DOZEN_PRICE * EGG_DOZEN;` instead of `double DozenEgg =DOZEN_PRICE * answer;`?

Comment: what output do you expect? what output do you get?

Comment: There's a one line error I found and I just noticed it now

Comment: double SingleEgg = EGG_PRICE * remainder;
double DozenEgg = DOZEN_PRICE * answer;

Comment: As a general principal to improve your code using more descriptive names for your variables would be helpful for both you and anyone reviewing your code, for example answer (dozenEggCount) and remainder (singleEggCount)

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation is the problem I guess.

```
double DozenEgg =DOZEN_PRICE * EGG_DOZEN;
```

This is not related to the input of the user. Instead, try:

```
double DozenEgg= DOZEN_PRICE * answer;
```

Comment: thank you I just noticed it!